# Looking for a terminal

Tags: command-line

Can someone tell me what kind of Terminal is used in the following figure:

[image: in this figure]

Does it color text that way? If not, is there any plugin for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although xmonad and i3 are good guesses, this is actually [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/), a terminal multiplexer (I know because I use it constantly).  It is an invaluable tool that allows you to create and manage multiple sessions (like browser windows), tabs (like browser tabs), and panes (like multiple tabs shown at once, as seen in your screenshot).  You can get it by installing the `tmux` package (`sudo apt-get install tmux`), and I highly recommend starting off with [this excellent tutorial](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/a-tmux-crash-course).

Most of the tmux "panes" with colored text are [`vim`](http://www.vim.org/) instances.  vim is a unique and immensely powerful text editor.  Check out first [this primer](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/the-vim-learning-curve-is-a-myth), and then [this tutorial](http://yannesposito.com/Scratch/en/blog/Learn-Vim-Progressively/).  If you ever have to do any significant amount of programming, vim will be one of your best friends.

Comment: Is it possible to customize its colors to make them appears like the posted screenshot ?

Comment: @AmurayuYukiko Yes.  That person has almost certainly used a pre-made theme to make vim look the way it does (vim supports themes and plugins, and has many of both).  Unfortunately, I am not familiar with that particular theme - if you don't like vim's default look, I would suggest trying out [Solarized](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized), which I personally enjoy a lot.  Aside from that, you might have to either (1) find the theme online through an exhaustive search or (2) hack an existing theme to your liking.

Comment: But how to install Solarized? Because when I run `mv solarized.vim ~/.vim/colors/` after having downloaded it and `cd vim-colors-solarized/colors` refering to its github's documentation, Terminal tells me that `~/.vim` couldn't be found.

Comment: Ah, that's because there's no `.vim` folder.  Try `mkdir -p ~/.vim/colors`, which will create both ~/.vim and ~/.vim/colors.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like [xmonad](http://xmonad.org/) window manager (see [this screenshot](http://www.haskell.org/wikiupload/8/80/Screen-rob-dzen.png)). It is OK if most of the things you do is in various terminal sessions but I found it a bit annoying when dealing with multi-window apps (like gimp or skype).

Comment: It might be xmonad, but it doesn't have the characteristic red box around the focused window. There are other tiling window managers. My guess is that this one is i3.